# For loop or lapply loop for simple automation question

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

```
table(one[YEAR == 2002, "PR1", with=FALSE])[c("8151", "8152", "8153",
                  "0070", "0071", "0072", "0073","0081", "0082", "0083",
                  "0084", "8154", "8155", "8005", "8006")]
```

I am using the `data.table` package to do simple tabulations. Can someone indicate how I could do this same tabulation for `2003`, `2004`, `2005` up to `2015`? It would be by altering `YEAR == 2002`, but I am not sure how to do it in a for loop/apply function without copying and pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following :

```
library(data.table)
# I create a data.table that resembles yours
n_lines <- length(rep(2002:2015,4))
one <- data.table::data.table("YEAR" = rep(2002:2015,4),
                             "PR1" = c(rep("8151",n_lines/4), rep("8153",n_lines/4),
                                       rep("8154",n_lines/4), rep("8158",n_lines/4)))
# Then I use .N by values of PR1 and YEAR and select only the few values of PR1 that interest me as in your code (but I only selected 8151 and 8153 in this example):

one[,.N,by = .(PR1,YEAR)][PR1 %in% c("8151", "8153")]
```

The first lines of the result are:

```
   PR1 YEAR N
1: 8151 2002 1
2: 8151 2003 1
3: 8151 2004 1
4: 8151 2005 1
5: 8151 2006 1
6: 8151 2007 1
```

You get the count for each PR1 value for each specific year in the variable N.

Hope it helps